# VB.NET - Check if webbrowser's url has changed

Tags: vb.net, url, webbrowser-control

So basically I am asking how to check if the URL of the webbrowser has changed (is diferrent from the previous one).

Thank you.

Comment: Different from one changing pages on the same website or changing web sites?

Comment: Many ways, this has been answered numerous times here. Have you thought about keeping a variable and check it?

Answer (score -1):

You can check ...

```
 Sub webbrowser1_Complete(ByVal sender As Object, _
        ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

       //Webbrowser1.url property to get valu of url
    End Sub
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Ok from what I can understand from your question this is what I would do.
 First create a `structure`this will allow you to store data that you may want to use again.
 Next create a `Function` in this case with a Boolean return that checks to see if `WebBrowser1`'s current url is the same as the one we have stored within our structure.
And once you have done that, I would create a new `WebBrowser1 Event` in this case `WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` to trigger the Function to compare both the WebBrowser1 url textbox and the structures stored string when a web page as completely loaded.

```
Public Class Form1

Dim urlSettings As urlSetting
Structure urlSetting
    Public url As String
End Structure

Private Function checkURL(url As String) As Boolean
    Dim changed As Boolean = True
    If Not urlSettings.url = url Then
        changed = False
    End If
    Return changed
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(New Uri(TextBox1.Text))
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    If Not checkURL(TextBox1.Text) Then
        urlSettings.url = TextBox1.Text
        MessageBox.Show("The URL has changed")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Of course you can modify so suit your needs, however this should get you on your way. :)
 MSDN Information
 Structure: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ft0z102.aspx 
WebBrowser Control : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx 
Return Statesments eg Function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e34641s.aspx

Comment: Let me note that I did not downvote this. I currently postponed this project and will continue it soon, trying your method.